# Sharing session over multiple servers with redis

Tags: redis, asp.net-core, .net-core, stackexchange.redis

I'm implementing a distributed redis cache in .NET Core to be shared among multiple .NET Core services in a microservice environment.  The microservices are on multiple servers behind a load-balancer on IIS.  The redis cache will be used to temporarily hold data related to individual users.  The redis server will be hosted internally.  I already have a cookie used for external authentication (AuthCookie), but I don't use Identity or Session as the user is expected to be logged in. I just send the AuthCookie to my authentication service, it authenticates and I fill my ClaimsPrincipal with the results.

Since my cache will be user specific, I thought it would be a good idea to utilize .Net Session with a redis distributed cache backing.  I want to use AuthCookie as the key, but it fails because it doesn't know how to decrypt it, which sucks.  Therefore, I have to have a second, .net session specific cookie.  The problem is, the session isn't working across servers on my load balancer, even with persisting my keys. Here's a simple version of my set up:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var host = "127.0.0.1";
    var port = "6379";
    var conn = $"{host}:{port}";
    var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(conn);

    services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys");

    services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
    {
        options.Configuration = conn;
        options.InstanceName = "master";
    });
    services.AddSession(options => options.CookieName = "NetSession");
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc();
}

public class RedisController : Controller
{
    public string Get(string key)
    {
        return HttpContext.Session.GetString(key);
    }

    public string Post([FromBody] CacheData data)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString(data.Key, data.Value);
        return $"Added {data.Key} with {data.Value}";
    }
}
```

This works fine on one server, but setting 3 instances of it up on my load balancer won't work.  I call the load-balancer, it sets a key on server A, redis will show as masterSOMEGUID, and a long "NetSession" cookie will be returned.  I call get on the load-balancer, server B picks it up, "NetSession" is sent, but when trying to find the key it generates a different GUID and can't find it.  If I hit server A again it will find it no problem.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

A separate solution I've found is to not use Session and just use IDistributedCache with the AuthCookie that's already on the requests.

```
public class RedisController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;
    public RedisController(IDistributedCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache
    }
    public string Get(string key)
    {
        return _cache.GetString($"{HttpContext.Request.Cookies["NetSession"]}{key}");
    }

    public string Post([FromBody] CacheData data)
    {
       _cache.SetString($"{HttpContext.Request.Cookies["NetSession"]}{data.Key}", data.Value);
        return $"Added {data.Key} with {data.Value}";
    }
}
```

This obviously creates a lot more entries on the redis store.  Is it bad form to do it this way?  It should be noted that I won't be storing user details, just user responses and other reusable information.

Comment: Did you resolve this?